# How to make a pre-loader like this and what is it called?

Tags: javascript, css, json, ajax, web

[how does youtube and other sites like fb make this preloader which shows outlines and grey boxes on the areas where the posts will appear after page fully loads. This link takes you to the screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RC4do.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take a look at

[animated-content-loader](https://github.com/gkhan205/animated-content-loader)

and [here](https://youtu.be/ZGJgXtwXAIc)

Comment: thanks sir @Vahid Alimohamadi